# How to allow only a specific account to interact with a Solana Program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, authority, security

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!(“example program id);

#[program]
pub mod example_program {

    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let example_account = &mut ctx.accounts.example_account;
        example_account.data = 0;
        Ok(())
    }
    
    pub fn set_data(ctx: Context<SetData>, new_data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let example_account = &mut ctx.accounts.example_account;
        // some conditional check here
    }
    
}          

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = authority, space=10240)] 
    pub example_account: Account<'info, ExampleAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetData<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub example_account: Account<'info, ExampleAccount>,
}

#[account]
pub struct ExampleAccount {
    pub data: u64,
}
```

example_account.data should be viewable (fetchable) by everyone but should be updatable only by program owner or some particular address.

In fn set_data, check if program owner:

```
if ctx.accounts.authority.is_signer() {
    // set data here
    Ok(())
}
```

In fn set_data, check if particular address:

```
if ctx.accounts.authority.key == “particular pubkey” {
    // set data here
    Ok(())
}
```

Are these conditions valid and secure enough? If not, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: can you clarify the title?  it sounds like you want to control the upgradability of the program itself, but the description talks about updating data of accounts owned by the program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use std::str::FromStr;

declare_id!("example program id");

const ALLOWED_PUBKEY: &str = "particular pubkey";

#[program]
pub mod example_program {

    //snip

    pub fn set_data(ctx: Context<SetData>, new_data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let example_account = &mut ctx.accounts.example_account;
        
        if Pubkey::from_str(ALLOWED_PUBKEY).unwrap() != *ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info().key
        {
            return Err(ErrorCode::Unauthorized.into());
        }

        // rest of the logic
    }
}

#[error]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Unauthorized")]
    Unauthorized
}
```

Comment: `ALLOWED_PUBKEY` probably needs to sign the tx for this to actually enforce anything.  Also base58 decoding is hella expensive, prefer [`pubkey!()`](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/macro.pubkey.html) from the `solana-program` crate instead

Comment: Yeah that's what I understood from the question. If a separate publicKey has to be the allowed updater, that has to be added in the transaction instruction struct as an `AccountInfo`.